# How to get the last used path for saving file

Tags: python, filepath

I want to make a tool of replace the path of image in markdown file by a http url. i implement that a shortcut can paste the http url of image from the clipborad. then i want to add a function that we can save the image in my computer, and use a shortcut to paste the http url of last saved file. so i need to get the last used path for saving file.

i have search the problem in google.but there are few relevant answers. in other words, maybe there are some solutions to get the newest saved file in PC.

Comment: i dont think there is a simple way of doing htis, you will have to save this path somewhere

Comment: Are you on Windows? If yes, you could look at the `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` folder.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters thank you, and i try it just now. i think it is a good solution in Windows. and i also have a Ubuntu computer, maybe i also can implement it in Ubuntu by similar way